# Rollback in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, rollback

Can I use `rollback` in a specific database table in Oracle?
I unintentionally changed one of the fields of an entire table and have already been queried in other tables. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean you updated a column and committed it and you now need to restore the data back to how it was before the update?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably not (the way you described it). Rollback will revert changes you've made during this transaction, i.e. since the last `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`). If you set a savepoint (which you did not), you could have rolled back since that point.

I'm not sure what you meant by saying "and have already been queried in other tables" - does it mean that values you modified have been used to modify other tables? If so, rollback will still revert those changes as well, unless they have been committed. Otherwise, see whether [Flashback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmflash.htm#BRADV80055) helps, as it allows you to *undo the past*.

Or, as a final resort, restore everything from backup. It'll indeed annul *everything* you (or anyone else) has done, which might not be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't commit the command, i.e. you didn't explicitally used "COMMIT", then you can rollback even if you have been queried other tables.